# Python: Get set of values, by multiplication

Tags: python

I want to get a list of values, by multiplication, like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]]
```

So, I tried:

```
rGen = (i for i in range(1, 4))
matriz = [[x * y for y in rGen] for x in rGen]
```

And I get:

```
[[2, 3]]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You want to multiply the elements in the inner lists??

Comment: Yes, in the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
>>> r=range(1,4)
>>> [[x * y for x in r] for y in r]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]]
```

The difference is how you use/assign the generator. As illustrated by this example (Python 2.x):

```
>>> r1=(i for i in range(1,4))
>>> r2=range(1,4)
>>> r3=[i for i in range(1,4)]

>>> r1
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x6ffffe1e4b0>
>>> r2
[1, 2, 3]
>>> r3
[1, 2, 3]

>>> [[x * y for x in r1] for y in r1]
[[2, 3]]
>>> [[x * y for x in r2] for y in r2]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]]
>>> [[x * y for x in r3] for y in r3]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]]
```

In the first example (`r1`), you get a generator object, which will only generate your sequence once, while in the other two examples you get lists, which you can use in a nested list comprehension (they will always evaluate to the same, no matter how many times you access them).

In Python 3.x, `range()` returns a different type, but the behavior is similar:

```
>>> r1=(i for i in range(1,4))
>>> r2=range(1,4)
>>> r3=[i for i in range(1,4)]

>>> r1
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x6ffffe7a518>
>>> r2
range(1, 4)
>>> r3
[1, 2, 3]

>>> [[x * y for x in r1] for y in r1]
[[2, 3]]
>>> [[x * y for x in r2] for y in r2]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]]
>>> [[x * y for x in r3] for y in r3]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same generator (rGen) for both your outer and inner loop. What you should do is:

```
matrix = [[x * y for y in range(1,4)] for x in range(1,4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

To return the product of elements of each list, you could do something like this,

```
>>> import operator
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]]
>>> [reduce(operator.mul, i, 1) for i in a]
[6, 48, 162]
>>>
```